# Print Options(Excel Iterop) Issue with horizontal page breaks?

Tags: c#, excel, printing, interop

I am having problems with setting horizontal page breaks. No matter what row I set the first page break to it ALWAYS is set the `row 87`

This is the code I am using. (I checked to see if I was accidentally setting the page break again below this code, but I was not) So this is all of the code I am using to setup the print settings.

```
int pageCount = 2;    

string defprinter = null;
defprinter = xlApplication.ActivePrinter;

xlWorkSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks();
xlApplication.ActivePrinter = defprinter;

var with = xlWorkSheet.PageSetup;

with.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4;
with.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait;

// Fit Sheet on One Page 
with.Zoom = false;
with.FitToPagesWide = 1;
with.PrintArea = @"$A$1:$I$" + (pageCount * 71);                
with.FitToPagesTall = pageCount;

xlWorkSheet.HPageBreaks.Add(xlWorkSheet.Range["A72"]);
xlWorkSheet.HPageBreaks.Add(xlWorkSheet.Range["A143"]);

// Normal Margins
with.LeftMargin = xlApplication.InchesToPoints(0.5);
with.RightMargin = xlApplication.InchesToPoints(0.5);
with.TopMargin = xlApplication.InchesToPoints(0.5);
with.BottomMargin = xlApplication.InchesToPoints(0.5);
```

I have spent the better part of two days trying all different settings with no luck. No matter what I do, the first `PageBreak` is always set the `row 87` and not `row 72`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Tried this code on a different PC today and it works as it should. So now the issue is identified as being something to do with what is going on in Excel on that particular machine. OS is Windows 10 BTW.

So even though it works, this is still an issue as I can't have it sporadically working on some users PC's and not on others.

Comment: Does it help if you remove the `FitToPagesTall` line? That seems in conflict with setting page breaks.

Comment: @DougGlancy, tried that, unfortunately that does nothing to help this. In fact taking that line out does more harm than good, it allows multiple pages to fit on one page.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. I converted your code to VBA and it works correctly on my sample worksheet. Have you tried running this on a newly created sheet? I suppose that might help you discover whatever issue is lurking in the background of your targeted sheet.

Comment: @DougGlancy, thanks for trying, I am also from a VBA background and by all accounts this should work. Also I should have mentioned that all page breaks set after the first one are also always 15 rows after from where I set them in code.

Comment: @DougGlancy, sorry , missed that first question. This is a newly created sheet in C# app, so there should be no problems there.